# jQuery - Hide last child <td> from <table>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide if the hobby doesn't have value (empty). But if the hobby has value is still show. How to condition it? I try using jQuery.

```js
$("tr:last-child td:last-child").css("font-weight","bold")

if($("tr:last-child td:last-child").length < 1){
 $("tr:last-child").hide()
}
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin:4px 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hobby</td>
    <td>Sleeping</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hobby</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) `tr` if the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of the `td` is blank.

```js
$("tr:last-child td:last-child").each(function(index, td) {
  if($(td).text() === ""){
    $(td).parent().hide();
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin:4px 0
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hobby</td>
    <td>Sleeping</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hobby</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `text()` to get the text of `td`

```js
$("tr:last-child td:last-child").each(function(index,element){
    $(element).css("font-weight","bold");
});
$("tr:last-child td:last-child").each(function(index,element){
    if($.trim($(element).text()).length == 0){
       $(element).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin:4px 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hobby</td>
    <td>Sleeping</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hobby</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if($("tr:last-child td:last-child").length < 1){
    $("tr:last-child").hide()
}
```

to:

```
if($("tr:last-child td:last-child").text().length < 1){
    $("tr:last-child").hide()
}
```